# How to find first and last values within query sorted by another column

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to coding and this is the most complex query I have tried writing.

I am trying to create a query that will find the first and last entry for meters sorted by bunker_id within a date range. There are 12 different systems that have their meters captured when they are used.

I have several MySQL tables to track usage of systems and component configurations.
One table has a log of meters for all the systems. What I am trying to do is query this table between Date A and Date B, and receive the first and last meter values within the date range for each system. They systems may not be used everyday, but on occasion will have multiple entries in a day.

I am looking to have a query run through POST on a web page with selectors for the days and the system id's. The data will be output into an HTML table.

| date | bunker_id | power_on_hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | A | 26115.50 |
| 01-02-2022 | B | 28535.13 |
| 01-02-2022 | A | 26257.38 |
| 01-03-2022 | B | 28682.73 |

What I am trying to return

| bunker_id | starting_meters | ending_meters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 26115.50 | 26257.38 |
| B | 28535.13 | 28682.73 |

The query that I have sets the starting and ending hours as the same value. I tried using MAX and MIN, but everything breaks if someone were to enter 0 for the meter.

```
SELECT 
        lu_bunkers.bunker_name as 'bunker_name', 
        lu_bunkers.bunker_sn, 
        SUM(system_utilization.hours_used) as 'total_hours', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN system_utilization.use_id = '1' THEN system_utilization.hours_used ELSE 0 END) as 'maintenance_hours',
        SUM(CASE WHEN system_utilization.use_id = '2' THEN system_utilization.hours_used ELSE 0 END) as 'working_rf_hours',
        SUM(CASE WHEN system_utilization.use_id = '3' THEN system_utilization.hours_used ELSE 0 END) as 'working_no_rf_hours',
        SUM(CASE WHEN system_utilization.use_id = '4' THEN system_utilization.hours_used ELSE 0 END) as 'acd_hours',
        ((SUM(system_utilization.hours_used))/ ((DATEDIFF('2022-02-24', '2021-01-01')+1)*5/7*12))*100 as net_utilization,
        ((DATEDIFF('2022-02-24', '2021-01-01')+1)*(5/7)*12) as num_hours,
        (SELECT system_meters.power_on_hours WHERE system_utilization.date_used BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2022-02-24' ORDER BY system_utilization.date_used DESC LIMIT 1) as 'ending_hours',
        (SELECT system_meters.power_on_hours WHERE system_utilization.date_used BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2022-02-24' ORDER BY system_utilization.date_used ASC LIMIT 1) as 'starting_hours'
      FROM system_utilization 
      LEFT JOIN lu_bunkers ON system_utilization.bunker_id = lu_bunkers.bunker_id 
      LEFT JOIN lu_use ON system_utilization.use_id = lu_use.use_id 
      LEFT JOIN system_meters ON system_utilization.id = system_meters.utilization_id
      WHERE system_utilization.date_used BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2022-02-24' AND system_utilization.bunker_id LIKE '%'
      GROUP BY system_utilization.bunker_id
      ORDER BY lu_bunkers.bunker_name
```

Comment: It will be easy to understand if put expected result of query.

Comment: Would it work if you add in the where clause :  "AND system_meters.power_on_hours > 0" ?

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.x so you can use window functions?

Answer (score 0):

2 possible solutions

Using Joins

```sql
SELECT
    a.`bunker_id`,
    b.`power_on_hours` as `starting_meters`,
    c.`power_on_hours` as `ending_meters`
FROM `yourtable` a
LEFT JOIN `yourtable` b
    ON (
         SELECT `date`
          FROM `yourtable`
          WHERE `bunker_id` = a.`bunker_id`
          ORDER BY `date`
          LIMIT 1
    ) = b.`date`
    AND a.`bunker_id` = b.`bunker_id`
LEFT JOIN `yourtable` c
    ON (
         SELECT `date`
          FROM `yourtable`
          WHERE `bunker_id` = a.`bunker_id`
          ORDER BY `date` DESC
          LIMIT 1
    ) = c.`date`
    AND a.`bunker_id` = c.`bunker_id`
GROUP BY a.`bunker_id`
```

Using subqueries on columns

```sql
SELECT
    a.`bunker_id`,
    (
      SELECT `power_on_hours`
          FROM `yourtable`
          WHERE `bunker_id` = a.`bunker_id`
          ORDER BY `date` LIMIT 1
     ) as `starting_meters`,
    (
      SELECT `power_on_hours`
          FROM `yourtable`
          WHERE `bunker_id` = a.`bunker_id`
          ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1
     ) as `ending_meters`
FROM `yourtable` a
GROUP BY a.`bunker_id`
```